# Display tweets from twitter API from user input

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm a beginner at javascript/jquery and completely new to API's and I'm wondering if anyone could help me with something

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a user enter a keyword/phrase into a textbox, they click search and the page returns a list of people who have that word in their tweet.

I have so far been able to display results from a hard-coded keyword (which I got from a website) but when trying to change it I am getting nothing back.

Here is the working one with hard code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=earthquake&lang=en&callback=?', function (data) {
            var data = data.results;
            var html = "<ul>";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += "<li><a href='http://twitter.com/" + data[i].from_user + "'>@"
                          + data[i].from_user + "</a>: " + data[i].text + "</li>";
            }
            html += "</ul>"
            $('.content').html(html);
        });
    });
</script>

<h2>Twitter</h2>
<div class="content">
</div>
```

And here is the code I'm working on now

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        var button= document.getElementById('searchTwitter');
        button.onclick= function(){
            var text = document.getElementById('search').value;
        }
        var baseUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search";


        var query = document.getElementById('<%=searchTwitter.ClientID%>').value;

        $(document).ready(function () {


            $.ajax({

                url: baseUrl + '&text' + '&lang=en&callback=?',

                dataType: "jsonp",

                success: showResults
            });
        });
            function showResults(data) {

                var data = data.results;
                var html = "<ul>";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    html += "<li><a href='http://twitter.com/" + data[i].from_user + "'>@"
                              + data[i].from_user + "</a>: " + data[i].text + "</li>";
                }
                html += "</ul>"
                $('.content').html(html);

        }



    </script>

    <asp:TextBox ID="search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="searchTwitter" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been trying to find a way to do this for days.

thanks a lot

Comment: Jsfiddle.com just gives me back a load of sponsored listings?basically I just want to return tweets from users with that keyword in it. I will upload some sort of demo later as I am away from laptop at the minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example of what you are describing: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEjey/. You should be able to adapt it to your ASP code.

Relevant code below.

**JQuery**

```
$("#SearchButton").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' + $('#TextSearch').val() + '&lang=en&callback=?', function (data) {
            var data = data.results;
            var html = "<ul>";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += "<li><a href='http://twitter.com/" + data[i].from_user + "'>@"
                          + data[i].from_user + "</a>: " + data[i].text + "</li>";
            }
            html += "</ul>"
            $('.content').html(html);
        });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Twitter</h2>
Search for: <input id="TextSearch" type="text" /> <input type="button" id="SearchButton" value="Go" />
<div class="content"></div>​
```

​---

**EDIT 0**

Okay, the code below works. The `<asp:Button` automatically causes a postback so you don't see anything ever get loaded. You either need to use `<input type="button" ...` instead or stop the normal events from occurring using `event.preventDefault();` as I did below.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h2>Twitter</h2>
    <asp:TextBox id="TextSearch" runat ="server"/> 
    <asp:Button id="SearchButton" runat="server"  Text="Search"/>
    <div class="content"></div>​
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SearchButton").click(function () {

                event.preventDefault(); // ADD THIS LINE TO YOUR CODE

                $('.content').html("<em>loading...<em>");
                $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' + $('#TextSearch').val() + '&lang=en&callback=?', function (data) {
                    var data = data.results;
                    var html = "<ul>";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        html += "<li><a href='http://twitter.com/" + data[i].from_user + "'>@" + data[i].from_user + "</a>: " + data[i].text + "</li>";
                    }
                    html += "</ul>";
                    $('.content').html(html);
                })
                .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
                .error(function() { alert("error"); })
                .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the replys, both your solutions make sense however I still cannot get any output to return on ASP. http://jsfiddle.net/n8ZE8/ this is what I have got so far, do I need to create an OnClick event on the asp:Button or was it sufficient to have that in the javascript? and then what would the code look like in the designer for the onClick?

Comment: thanks for the edit! works perfectly, I feel my understanding of the subject has now improved aswell

Comment: Good to hear. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making an ajax request on document ready, rather than when the button is clicked. I also don't see where you're adding the value from the text box to the query. Here's how you could change your code:

```
//this code will run when the page loads and set up the button so the 
//onclick event executes your function
$(document).ready(function () {
    var button = document.getElementById('<%=searchTwitter.ClientID%>');
    //you need to make the ajax request in this function, because this 
    //is fired when the search button is clicked 
    button.onclick = function() {
        var text = document.getElementById('search').value;
        var baseUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json";
        var query = document.getElementById('<%=search.ClientID%>').value;
        $.ajax({
            //you're building the request url here, with the text from the 
            //box as the q parameter
            url: baseUrl + '?q=' + query + '&lang=en&callback=?',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: showResults
        });
    };
});

//this function can be defined outside ready()
function showResults(data) {
    var data = data.results;
    var html = "<ul>";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html += "<li><a href='http://twitter.com/" + data[i].from_user + "'>@"
            + data[i].from_user + "</a>: " + data[i].text + "</li>";
    }
    html += "</ul>";
    //I'm assuming you have a div with a content class on your page
    $('.content').html(html);
}
```

You might also want to try out the Chrome developer tools (or Firebug in Firefox). You can set breakpoints and see what's happening at each step. You can also see what requests have been sent and the data returned. That will help give you a better handle on what's going on.